# How to merge SQL Server data efficiently?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I have three tables in SQL Server where I need to combine all matching rows from all tables into a fourth `MergedTable` that will contain all the columns from the three individual tables based on the `U_ID` column.

Is there a way of doing this via T-SQL in a stored procedure, or should I just create a loop function in C#?

Bottom line is this is going to be executed from a command from a website, so it needs to be something I can encapsulate into an MVC project or component.

Here is an example of the tables.

Table 1:

```
U_ID       ClientNumber   OrderDate   Amount
---------------------------------------------
BB000Kw    1920384        5/14/2013   1093.39
AA000bM    3839484        12/8/2012   584.42
AA000gH    8294848        2/28/2014   4849.38
AA000md    3849484        4/31/2013   590.84
AA000mF    3998398        3/29/2013   448.82
AA000mG    9944848        11/28/2014  98.85
AA000mn    0292938        10/31/2012  300.48
```

Table 2:

```
U_ID       Name                 Date
------------------------------------------
AA000bM    "Krivis, Jeffrey"    7/1/2002
AA000bv    "Saydah, Michael"    7/30/2002
AA000cA    "Byrne, Richard"     4/21/2003
AA000dd    "McNeil, Joseph"     6/10/2003
AA000dH    "Greenberg, Arnold"  1/16/2003
AA000gH    "Rich, Elwood"       7/5/2003
AA000id    "O'Neill, Robert J." 11/20/2002
AA000jf    "Patsey, Richard"    4/22/2003
AA000jr    "Jones, Arthur"      7/1/2002
AA000jU    "Toff, Ronald"       7/15/2002
AA000k4    "Anderson, Carl"     8/14/2002
BB000Kw    "Wilson, Sam"        3/9/2003
```

Table 3:

```
U_ID       Name
-----------------------------
AA000bM    Acme Company
AA000jr    Stockwell Industries
BB000ke    Gensen Motors
BB999di    Falstaff Cards
BB000dl    B and R Printing
BB000Kw    Go Golf Carts
AA000gH    Rich's Sandwiches
```

Resulting merged table

```
U_ID       ClientNumber   OrderDate   Amount     CustomerName         JoinDate     CompanyName
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
BB000Kw    1920384        5/14/2013   1093.39    "Wilson, Sam"        3/9/2003     Go Golf Carts
AA000bM    3839484        12/8/2012   584.42     "Krivis, Jeffrey"    7/1/2002     Acme Company
AA000gH    8294848        2/28/2014   4849.38    "Rich, Elwood"       7/5/2003     Rich's Sandwiches
```

Table 1 is the master table that the others are matched to.  You can see from the result that there will be only a subset of all the tables based on those that are matched from Table 1.

I'll be using MVC with the Entity Framework 6 and Linq-to-Entities, but if a T-SQL script is more efficient, then I should probably use that instead.

Which is the better way to go to get this result?

Comment: what about a join or instead, keep it normalized and use a view instead of a table?

Comment: what size data sets are you looking at?  E.g., how many rows per table?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a new table you can use `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM ...` query. In your case it would look like this:

```
SELECT t1.U_ID, t1.ClientNumber, t1.OrderDate, t1.Amount, 
       t2.Name as CustomerName, t2.Date as JoinDate, 
       t3.Name as CompanyName
INTO dbo.ResultingMergedTable
FROM Table1 t1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.U_ID = t2.U_ID
INNER JOIN Table3 t3 ON t1.U_ID = t3.U_ID
```

Keep in mind that if you are looking at really big data table this will take a lot of time to execute.

Comment: i suggest use the left outer join else you'll miss the records which are not in child tables

Comment: @mannyyysh It is not clear from description, whether it is INNER or LEFT join. It says that `Table 1 is the master table that the others are matched to` which seems to me as if it is INNER JOIN, but I can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can create a 4th table to do what you mentioned but if you are using sql you can create a view to do the same thing. A view is a virtual table.  We use this when we partition data as well as make a detailed record like described above.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx

http://www.sqlinfo.net/sqlserver/sql_server_VIEWS_the_basics.php

```
CREATE VIEW DetailView AS
(
   SELECT
     -- table1
     t1.U_ID,
 t1.ClientNumber,
 t1.OrderDate,
 t1.Amount,
 -- table2
 t2.Name,
 t2.Date as [JoinDate],
 -- table3
 t3.Name as [Company]
   FROM 
     table1 t1
     LEFT JOIN  
   table2 t2
     ON t1.U_ID = t2.U_ID
 LEFT JOIN
   table3 t3
     ON t1.U_ID = t3.U_ID
   WHERE
      t1.U_ID = t2.U_ID
  and 
  t1.U_ID = t3.U_ID
)
```